# Issue running 32-bit executable on 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, 64-bit, 32-bit, 32bit-64bit

I'm using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to convert HTML web pages to PDFs. This works perfectly on my 32-bit dev server [unfortunately, I can't ship my machine   :-p  ]. However, when I deploy to the web application's 64-bit server the following errors are displayed:
    (running from cmd.exe)

```
C:\>wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf
Loading pages (1/5)
QFontEngine::loadEngine: GetTextMetrics failed ()            ] 10%
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngine::loadEngine: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngine::loadEngine: GetTextMetrics failed ()            ] 36%
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
// ...etc....
```

and the PDF is created and saved... just WITHOUT text. All form-fields, images, borders, tables, divs, spans, ps, etc are rendered accurately...just void of any text at all.

Server information:

```
    Windows edition: Windows Server Standard Service Pack 2
    Processor: Intel Xeon    E5410 @ 2.33GHz 2.33 GHz
    Memory: 8.00 GB
    System type: 64-bit Operating System
```

**Can anyone give me a clue as to what is happening and how I can fix this?**

*Also, I wasn't sure what to tag/title this question with...so if you can think of better tags/title comment them or edit the question. :-)*

Comment: Web application? ;) did you turn IIS to use 32 bit mode?;)

Comment: yes, its for a web application. However, it doesn't work even if I run  it from the cmd line. And yes, I configured the web-server to use 32-bit mode. Thanks :-)

Comment: no one has a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a Windows Font service had crashed. A simple restart fixed the issue.